# Variable isn't defined but why?

Tags: typescript

I seem to be getting "test is not defined" for some reason. I have defined a variable exactly like this in another service file. Just wondering why it's not working in this particular code?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class OnlineTestService {
 // add setters and gettrers  according to your usage
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        var test = "";
        this.getJSON().subscribe(data => {
            return data;
        });
        this.getANSWERS().subscribe(data => {
            return data;
        });

    };

    questionAnswers(input){
        test = input;
    };
    retrieveAnswers(){
        return test;
    };

    public getJSON(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get("assets/questions.json");
    };

    public getANSWERS(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get("assets/answers.json");
    };

}
```

EDIT:

```
export class RegistrationService {
 // add setters and gettrers  according to your usage
    constructor(){
        var name = "";
    }
    addUser(input){
        name = input.name;
    }
    retrieveUser(){
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why *would* it be? Did you mean `this.test`? Also you never seem to use the result of your HTTP requests anywhere.

Comment: @jonrsharpe The data that gets sent into the parameter "input" through the "questonAnswers()" method, are the values from a dictionary in another component. I just need some variable to store this input data while I then send it out to another component. I have another service that does it like this: (see my latest edit)

Comment: `RegistrationService` doesn't work either, for the same reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined `var test` local to the scope of your constructor...

```
@Injectable()
export class OnlineTestService {
    test:string; //you have declare at the class level

 // add setters and gettrers  according to your usage
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        this.getJSON().subscribe(data => {
            return data;
        });
        this.getANSWERS().subscribe(data => {
            return data;
        });

    };

    questionAnswers(input){
        this.test = input;
    };

    retrieveAnswers(){
        return this.test;
    };

}
```

Comment: Ah I see. Sorry, noobie here. Thanks so much. Could you perhaps tell me why it works then in my latest edit on my question? I have it set up like that in another service and it works just fine, I'm confused

Answer (score 0):

you want 'test' to be a private object, not a var inside the constructor.  The way you have it is set up as a local variable which can't be read anywhere else.

Comment: I've tried making it "private test: string;" and it's still giving me the same error. Is that the correct way to set up private variable? You'll have to excuse my noob-ness, I'm pretty new to angular

Comment: Ah sorry, your answer was good thank you. I just forgot to call test by "this.test". Thanks for help! :)

Comment: Sure thing.  Feel free to mark as the answer if it helped you